# How to return Boolean from Dialog button?

Tags: android

I have the following situation:

I have a method that performs some checks of user inputs.

the method returns `true` or `false`.

Now my method pop ups some dialogs if it is the case.

I cannot return a Boolean form `onClick`, because `onClick` returns void.

**Please can anybody suggest me a workaround???**

Thanks!!!

```
public Boolean retrunvalue=false;
private Boolean performchecks() {

    if (!reminderdatepicked && !remindertimepicked) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                NewGenericEvent.this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.remindernotsettitle);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.remindernotmessage)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                    int id) {
                retrunvalue= true;//NOT A GOOD IDEA
                                                      //BECAUSE IT RETURNS TRUE
                                                      //ONLY WHEN performchecks()
                                                      //IS CALLED THE SECOND TIME
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.no,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                    int id) {
                retrunvalue= false;
            }
        });

        builder.create().show();
        return retrunvalue;
    }


    return true;
}
```

Comment: @Maxim Shoustin yes, but if the user clicks the positive button it should return `true` possibility immediately, not when `performchecks()` is called a second time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you try to do is to block main UI Thread till get response from click on `OK`.
Not good idea.

You can find some conversation in [Google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/-PGsJYMa3PU) about that issue, but solution they suggest is too complicated for your goal (your choice).

Anyways I would create Handler that should take care about button click, like:

```
protected static final int DIALOG_CLICKED = 1;

private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        String txt;
        switch (msg.what) {
        case DIALOG_CLICKED:
            Boolean bool = Boolean.parseBoolean(msg.obj.toString());
            // When user press on "OK",
            // your braking point goes here
            break;
        default:
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    }
};
```

After modify `performchecks`:

```
private void performchecks() {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.remindernotsettitle);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.remindernotmessage)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                    int id) {

                mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(DIALOG_CLICKED, true)); 
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.no,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                    int id) {
                mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(DIALOG_CLICKED, false)); 
            }
        });

        builder.create().show();           
}
```

Comment: thanks Maxim! I was thinking something like that, the point is that there is no need to perform the checks inside the `onClick`, the checks are performed before, I need to return `true` if the positive button is clicked, and `false` if the negative button is clicked... :-/

Comment: So this is a reason why we use AsyncTask run inbackground. When user pres on Ok, we run asynctask and return true only after perform checks

Comment: doInBackground returns true instead dialog (as I know)

Comment: Always FALSE because the method doesn't "wait" for the action on the dialogs